# Use bootstrap 3 Scrollspy to show / hide a div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can I use bootstrap 3 Scrollspy to show/hide a `div`.

My Code

```
<div class-col-md-4"> 

<div class="mydiv" data-spy="scroll" data-offset="50">
My Text
</div>

</div>
```

I want to show `.mydiv` when the div scroll to top `50px`. Can someone tell me what CSS should I use to do this?

Comment: Seems in your code `</div` not closed properly, please close it `</div>`, and put some JS code if you have done

Comment: @Haresh Vidja sorry about that. its closed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jquery to do this see if this fits to you.

Here is the jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var myDiv = $('.mydiv');

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
      myDiv.show();
    } else {
      myDiv.hide();
    }

  });
});
```